# Access Toolbar (MaterialToolbar) from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, material-components-android

How can I access a `Toolbar` (actually a `MaterialToolbar`) from a `Fragment` using `activity.actionBar`?

**main_layout.xml** (extract):

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:background="#ffffff">

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
        
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**MainActivity** (extract):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        [..]
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
}
```

**MyFragment** (extract):

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    [..]
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val actNull = activity == null
        Timber.i("DEF: activity == null: $actNull")

        var barNull = activity?.actionBar == null
        Timber.i("DEF: activity.actionbar == null: $barNull")
    }
}
```

Output from the debug statements in the **MyFragment**:

```
DEF: activity == null: false
DEF: activity.actionbar == null: true
```

As I used `setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)` in the `MainActivity`, shouldn't `activity.actionbar` be non-null? What am I doing wrong here?

Hint: As far as I know I can alternatively use `activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar)`. This question is really about why `activity.actionBar` isn't working.

Comment: Use (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar

Comment: Thank you, that works! Please post as answer. Do you know why `activity.actionBar` doesn't work? Is `activity.actionBar` intended to be the "original" action bar, the one you don't have to add manually and that one as of today disables with the `NoActionBar` theme?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf not exactly. `android.app.ActionBar` and `androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar` are different. The `AppCompatActivity` handles in any case a `androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar`, if it is inflated by a layout or by theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar
```

Just a little explanation:

`activity` returns a `FragmentActivity` which handles an `android.app.ActionBar`.
You are using an `AppCompatActivity` which handles an `androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar`.
They are different.

Comment: I have a follow up question on this: Why can't I do `((activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar) as MaterialToolbar`? That gives me  `java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar`

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf It happens because the `ActionBar` is not a `Toolbar`. You can check the [source code](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/ToolbarActionBar.java).